# Proof regarding lebesgue measure (from Folland's book)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Q.** Let $\mu$ denote the Lebesgue measure on real line. If $E\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mu(E)<\infty$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a set $A$ which is a finite union of open intervals such that
$$\mu((E\backslash A)\cup(A\backslash E))<\epsilon$$

**Try**

It is clear that $(E\backslash A)$ and $(A\backslash E)$ are disjoint. So,$$\mu((E\backslash A)\cup(A\backslash E))=\mu(E\backslash A)+\mu(A\backslash E)$$

But I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: How was Lebesgue measure introduced?

Comment: thanks. I have a feeling that I got answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know (c.f. Lebesgue outer measure) that for every $\delta>0$ there are open intervals $I_1,I_2,\dots$ such that $E\subset\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ and such that $\mu(E)+\delta\geq\sum_k\mu(I_k)$. Try $A=\cup_{k=1}^{N}I_k$ for $N$ big enough.